# Is it true that $L+L^T$ has at most one negative eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $L$ is a non-symmetric Laplacian matrix, then $L+L^T$ is symmetric. Is it true that $L+L^T$ has at most one negative eigenvalue? I try many examples using Matlab numerically to find out that there is at most one negative eigenvalues, but I am not sure it is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. If $L+L^T$ has a negative eigenvalue (such as when $L=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 0&0}$), then $L'+L'^T$ can have as many negative eigenvalues as you like, when $L'=L\oplus L\oplus\cdots\oplus L$ is a direct sum of multiple copies of $L$.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I use the matrix $L$ you give but it turns out that $L+L^T$ has only one negative eigenvalue.

Comment: @winston Yes, and so $(L\oplus L)+(L\oplus L)^T$ has two negative eigenvalues, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for this simple answer.